# Email Service Handle signature Attachments

Tags: apex, apex-email-service, header, inboundservices

I have an email service that I need to save the Email and the attachments (if there are any) on the Email Message Object.

When I got an email with some signature (like a company signature inside the email) Its save inside the attachments as well.

I found some differences with a regular attachment and "Signature attachments", just wonder if I got it right - I didn't see it anywhere in SF docs.

When I see that one of the header's value is "inline" I know its a Signature and I'm ignoring it.

```
 for (Messaging.Inboundemail.BinaryAttachment bAttachment: binaryAttachments) {
     for (Messaging.InboundEmail.Header header: bAttachment.headers) {

         if (header.value.contains('inline;')) {
             flagIsInlineAttach = true;
             break;
         }
     }
     if (flagIsInlineAttach) {
         flagIsInlineAttach = false;
         continue;
     }
 }
```

Is that correct? Or does the "inline" value have another role here an I would miss some attachments?

If I do, what is the correct way to avoid saving those signatures as attachments?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inline` does represent an inline file, which should almost always be a gif, png, or jpeg (most clients won't inline non-image resources). However, context could be important. A user could inline a screenshot of an error message or something, for example. I can't say if that's a common use case for you, so you'll need to decide if you want to ignore such images or not.

Comment: No, it's not my use case. Thanks 